# Opencart Filters requesting http and hanging site up

Tags: ssl, https, opencart

I have an issue with my OpenCart install. I am currently using 2.0.3.1 on a dedicated server running Plesk.

I installed a Let's Encrypt SSL certificate. The website is running great and I have no issues with OpenCart requesting unsecure pages except when I click on a filter in the category page. It just hangs.

This is the error I get via Chrome developer tools. I apologize for having to blur out the domain. It's for a customer and i can't release it.

[image]

Here is my catalog config.php:

```
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://www.xxxxx.com/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://www.xxxxx.com/');

// DIR
define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/httpdocs/xxxxx/catalog/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', '/var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/httpdocs/xxxxx/system/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', '/var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/httpdocs/xxxxx/catalog/language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', '/var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/httpdocs/xxxxx/catalog/view/theme/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', '/var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/httpdocs/xxxxx/system/config/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', '/var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/httpdocs/xxxxx/image/');
define('DIR_CACHE', '/var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/httpdocs/xxxxx/system/cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', '/var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/httpdocs/xxxxx/system/download/');
define('DIR_UPLOAD', '/var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/httpdocs/xxxxx/system/upload/');
define('DIR_MODIFICATION', '/var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/httpdocs/xxxxx/system/modification/');
define('DIR_LOGS', '/var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/httpdocs/xxxxx/system/logs/');

// DB
define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysql');
define('DB_HOSTNAME', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'xxx');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'xxx');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'xxx');
define('DB_PORT', '3306');
define('DB_PREFIX', 'oc_');
```

Here is the admin config.php:

```
    // HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://www.xxxxx.com/admin/');
define('HTTP_CATALOG', 'http://www.xxxxx.com/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://www.xxxxx.com/admin/');
define('HTTPS_CATALOG', 'https://www.xxxxx.com/');

// DIR
define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/httpdocs/xxxxx/admin/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', '/var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/httpdocs/xxxxx/system/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', '/var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/httpdocs/xxxxx/admin/language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', '/var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/httpdocs/xxxxx/admin/view/template/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', '/var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/httpdocs/xxxxx/system/config/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', '/var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/httpdocs/xxxxx/image/');
define('DIR_CACHE', '/var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/httpdocs/xxxxx/system/cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', '/var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/httpdocs/xxxxx/system/download/');
define('DIR_UPLOAD', '/var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/httpdocs/xxxxx/system/upload/');
define('DIR_LOGS', '/var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/httpdocs/xxxxx/system/logs/');
define('DIR_MODIFICATION', '/var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/httpdocs/xxxxx/system/modification/');
define('DIR_CATALOG', '/var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/httpdocs/xxxxx/catalog/');

// DB
define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysql');
define('DB_HOSTNAME', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'xxx');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'xxx');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'xxx');
define('DB_PORT', '3306');
define('DB_PREFIX', 'oc_');
```

I do not have an htaccess file setup, with the Plesk install I haven't needed it.

Comment: Somewhere in your files you have full path like [http://www.domain-name.com/bla-bla](http://www.domain-name.com/bla-bla)

Comment: I understand that but It can't be a link in the page somewhere. I believe it to be in the actual opencart software somewhere. I'm hoping someone will have an idea of where to look.

Comment: Αs a last resort, use "Find in files" for **http://** with your favorite editor (Sublime, Notepad++ etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `HTTP_SERVER` for admin

`define('HTTP_SERVER', 'https://www.xxxxx.com/admin/');`

There's no reason to serve anything from admin with http.

Comment: You got it scott. Although changing it for the admin did not solve my problem, completely eliminating all http:// in my config files and changing them to https:// fixed my issue. Thanks for leading me there. :)

Answer (score 0):

It should be fixed in this commit: [Category links (canonical, prev, next) points to https if it is enabled](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/commit/5fdd12b2bfc78e3b40e68b476daf72c436198362)

Comment: So, my catalog/controller/product/category.php doesn't have lines 351-362. It goes from 349-364 right away. Do I just add in the "corrected code"? Thanks for your help man! I really appreciate it!